# Trying to stop timer but timer is not stopping

Tags: flutter, dart

as you can see in image section i am printing whatever value i pass to the function [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVMKp.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVMKp.png)This is the code Snippet I'm using for timer.
I'm passing this function as bool value,
pass `true` value, when I need to start timer and this condition is works fine.
But when this function receive `false` value, timer is not stopping. I have also tried some other logics but still not working..

Please let me know where I am wrong?

```dart
Timer _timer;
    
    
      startTimer(value) {
        print("Recording values...........$value");
        const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
        _timer = new Timer.periodic(
          oneSec,
          (Timer timer) {
            if (mounted && value == true) {
              setState(() {
                seconds = seconds + 1;
              });
            } else if (mounted && value == false){
              setState(() {
                _timer.cancel();
              });
            }
          },
        );
      }
```

Comment: Timer won't stop because you're not setting the value as false

Comment: Yes i am pasing value false to this function! even i check this by printing it in a consoleprint("Recording values...........$value");

Comment: where you call startTimer() ?

Comment: also you recreate timer every time, this `if (_timer != null && value == false) _timer.cancel();` must be before this line `_timer = new Timer.periodic(`

Comment: i call startTime on Start Recording and pass value true and when longPressEnd: i pass false value

Comment: The first time you call this function and passing 'True', it will work as intended. But when you call this function when longPressEnd and passing 'False', it will create another timer. So the first timer will always been catching 'True', while the 2nd timer will catch 'False'. See @Dude solution

Comment: so what should i do??? should i remove new keyword?

Comment: @Dude could you please correct this given snippt , i am not understanding your logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 startTimer(value) {
    print("Recording values...........$value");
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    if (_timer != null && !value) _timer.cancel();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) {
        if (mounted && value) {
          setState(() {
            seconds++;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
```